# Any way to stream shoutcast url aac+ stream using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, shoutcast

Hi im trying to reproduce an stream shoutcast url this is my code in phonegap:

http://pastebin.ca/2228987

i get just terrible noises no music my url is http://streaming507.com:8026/

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using native android code in eclipse instead of phonegap.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on iOS shoutcast stream works on Android it doesn't how did you fix?